# Node.js - Is there a way to set "apn" module for both production and development purposes?

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications, node-apn

I am using **node-apn** module to send push notifications to ios devices. Below
you can see my config setting;

```
apnConfig: {
        providerOptions: {
          token: {
          key: path.join(__dirname, 'keys', 'tokenkey.p8'),
          keyId: 'XXXXX',
          teamId: 'XXXXX'
          },
          production: true  
        },
        topic: 'X.X.X.X'
      },
```

This config does not work in the development environment. I can not send notifications for testing purposes to development devices. I have to set  the  "`production:`" value as "`false`"  to send notification to development. Then I have to change as "`true`" for sending to production.

In the live environment,  I want to use my server both dev and prod purposes. So I can not change the production value always. Is there any way for working with both dev and prod in node-apn module ?

Comment: why don't you use an environment variable to set `true/false` depending on which env you're building for?